# How to use ItemContainerTransitions when using custom GridViewItem template?

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

When I replace ListItemPresenter in ControlTemplate of `GridView.ItemContainerStyle`, the ItemContainerTransitions stop working.

How do I achieve the [Staggering effect](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/04/17/Animating-list-items-within-Windows-apps.aspx), when using custom ItemContainerTemplate?

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="50" IsStaggeringEnabled="True" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>

    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,18,18"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="350"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="350"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <toolkit:DropShadowPanel x:Name="dropShadowPanel" OffsetY="2" BlurRadius="4"  ShadowOpacity="0.3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                                 Transitions="{TemplateBinding Transitions}">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Path x:Name="Icon" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Data="{StaticResource PersonAddIconGeometry}" Stretch="Uniform"
                                          Stroke="{StaticResource HighlightBrush1}" StrokeThickness="2" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Row="1"
                                               Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="42" FontWeight="Light" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="textBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
                                            <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            <Setter Target="Icon.Stroke" Value="White" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="textBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
                                            <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            <Setter Target="Icon.Stroke" Value="White" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="dropShadowPanel" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Icon.Stroke" Value="Gray" />
                                            <Setter Target="Root.Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </toolkit:DropShadowPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
<GridView/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ItemContainerTransitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemContainerTransitions) can work with custom item container. The problem here is related to the custom panel you've used. You can test this with a simplest GridView like the following:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="50" IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>

    <!--<GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>-->
</GridView>
```

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Here the `EntranceThemeTransition` works. But if you use the `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanel`, you will find the transition does not work anymore.

Generally, when using data binding in an [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol), the `ItemContainerTransitions` can only work with panels that support virtualization such as [ItemsWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx) or [ItemsStackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel.aspx). If we use some other panels like `StackPanel`, it won't work.

So to fix this problem, you can replace `StackPanel` with `ItemsStackPanel`. `ItemsStackPanel` arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically just the same as `StackPanel`.

If you do want to use `StackPanel` then you can add items to the [Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_Items) collection instead of setting the [ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsSource) property to a data source.

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" Loaded="MyGridView_Loaded">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="50" IsStaggeringEnabled="True" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
</GridView>
```

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

private void MyGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in Items)
        MyGridView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I've figured this out, but another related issue appeared. When the transitions are applied, either binding (Path and textBlock) in my custom item container does not work or it is rendering issue. They only work item ItemTemplate.